# Android Studio 3.1 does not showing 'android' option under Tools menu

Tags: android, android-menu, android-studio-3.1

I am using android studio 3.1 for some development.
But Its does not showing `android` option under `Tools` menu. Whereas Android studio 3.0 doesn't have this problem.

Here is the screenshot of android studio 3.1 Tools menu:

[image]

See missing the `android` option.
I think this is some configuration related problem as it doesn't exist in android studio 3.0. Basically I need `Enable ADB Integration` option. Is there any way to show the option in Tools menu?

Comment: is this a problem or a bug report? If problem, specify what the problem is, if bug report -> post on google bug report tracker, not here

Comment: Don't know its problem or android studio bug. That's why asking here.

Comment: how are we supposed to know. Did you read the patch notes?

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking for a way to fix the buggy connection to a physically connected USB device without restarting Android Studio, this might help:

**Preferences** > **Build, Execution & Deployment** > **Debugger**

Then check or uncheck the box **Use libusb backend**

[image]

Comment: Couldn't find on AS 3.1.3.

Comment: there is no such a thing in version 3.5

Answer (score 5):

Google has **officially** removed the Memory Monitor tool in the Android studio 3+ and brings new Tool that is **Memory Profile**.

From the [documentation for the tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html):

> To open **Memory Profiler**, follow these step:
>
> 1. Click View > Tool Windows > Android Profiler (you can also click Android Profiler in the toolbar).
>
>    2. Select the device and app process you want to profile from the Android Profiler toolbar. If you've connected a device over USB but don't see it listed, ensure that you have enabled USB debugging.
>    3. Click anywhere in the MEMORY timeline to open the Memory Profiler.

See the [Google's Official Statement](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory?utm_source=udacity&utm_medium=course&utm_campaign=android_basics).

Answer (score 4):

Can u find the android in the Help>action?
like shown below.

> click on Find Action or Ctrl+Shift+A

[image]

> After that try searching"Android" in the search bar.
>   [image]

Comment: Please review my answer and tell me if r u able to find "android Tab" now or not?

Comment: No this is only displaying the rest of the menu items under android

Answer (score 1):

From the android studio 3.1, android option menu is deleted and you can read it from the documentation : https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html
if you want to open it, open from the android-sdk/tools/ directory then run monitor.bat
hope this help you guys

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after update android studio separated that field from tools and located it at bottom-right corner.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue after many tried I found the solution. In Android Studio 3.1.3,
Click File> Settings > Debugger > Uncheck *Kill the debug process immediately* and apply then again check it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the Android options **are already there**, provided without an additional sub-menu.

Here is what there is under the Tools menu in Android Studio 3.0, all options are same, just grouped together:

[image]

EDIT: There are some missing items such as 'Enable ADB Integration', for these you can always use the **Help > Find Action...** where you type in the search, it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: How can I find 'Enable ADB Integration' option?

Comment: @Md.AliHossain - I edited my answer, added the missing part.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find it in android studio 3.1. Did you check in 3.1?

Comment: @Md.AliHossain - you searched with **Help > Find Action...** and still couldn't find it?

Comment: Exactly I couldn't find it in android studio 3.1

Comment: @Md.AliHossain - then it's probably not there. Consider returning on 3.0, it's the official stable version at the moment

Answer (score 0):

adb seems to be deprecated in android studio 3.1. On Ubuntu I can run adb from the command line using Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb and I can run the Device Monitor using Android/Sdk/tools/monitor. More information may be available at https:/developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Profiler if you want to measure app performance and inspect activity for CPU, RAM and Network instead of using ADB Integration.

[image: here]

For more Info. check this out [Measure app performance with Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add navigation folder inside res and add a file like below file. In this file, we have two activities that are UI will show in this navigation file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainActivity">

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
        android:name="com.noman.navigation.MainActivity"
        android:label="activity_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/oneActivity"
        android:name="com.noman.navigation.OneActivity"
        android:label="one_activity"
        tools:layout="@layout/one_activity" />
</navigation>
```

you can also add this navigation via right click in res folder and section add a new resource.

By this, you will be able to see navigations on UI.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Android Studio 3.5.2, the location of the NDK bundle was not set in Preferences.  To set NDK location, **File -> Project Settings -> SDK Location** then look for second field **Android NDK Location**. Once I provided the folder location for NDK bundle, Android Studio synced gradle again and built the app and showed all Android options under Tools.

link to image -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlGl4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the following below steps to check memory usage.
Click View > Tool Windows > Profiler (you can also click Profile  in the toolbar).
Select the device and app process you want to profile from the Android Profiler toolbar. If you've connected a device over USB but don't see it listed, ensure that you have enabled USB debugging.
Click anywhere in the MEMORY timeline to open the Memory Profiler.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same problem.

Check you don't have any errors on the bottom of android studio. I got one with sdk build. If you got the same click on the link in error log.

**Next go to file -> settings -> Appearance&Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars**

**Roll up Main menu -> Tools.**

**Choose Android.**

Click on 'Apply' button and 'OK'. 
Wait for a while (gradle progress-bar on the bottom).

I hope that I solve your problem.