# How to profile Android application without USB connection to device?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, performance-testing

I want to profile an Android application on a physical Android device without using a USB connection from the device to my computer. The device's USB port is being used by a peripheral that is essential to my application.

I'm using the [Android Wifi ADB](https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB/) Android Studio plugin and have successfully connected the device to utilise the bridge to Android Studio 3.2.1

When I attempt to begin a new profiling session using the Android Profiler my connected device appears to have "no debuggable processes."

How can I profile my application without a USB connection to my Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution thanks to [Unity's list of Android profilers](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/android-profiling-tools).

At this time on Android Studio version 3.2.1 ADB and the Android Profiler do not work together over WiFi.

For my case I've found [`simpleperf`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/) to be acceptable, a tool which includes functionality to generate [CPU flame graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html). I used `run_simpleperf_without_usb_connection.py` specifically, [as documented in the simpleperf README available here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/doc/README.md#run_simpleperf_without_usb_connection-py).

Answer (score 0):

You need to `enable adb integration`, 
Go to `Tools-->Android-->Check Enable ADB Integration`

It was a default feature a few versions ago but now it has been disabled by default.

Comment: Great to hear! I've searched Tools but can't find Android and I can't find Enable ADB Integration searching with the `Find Action` tool. I'm on Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3O5ofeX.png on Android Studio 3.2.1 I don't have the option. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49625983/7015599 suggests it was removed from Android Studio 3.2

Comment: Preferences > Build, Execution & Deployment > Debugger

Then check or uncheck the box Use libusb backendhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904505/android-studio-3-1-does-not-showing-android-option-under-tools-menu

Comment: Thank you but I've attempted that fix already and still no success. This is a lot of comments so I've created another post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53229325/7015599