# How to locate Tools -> Android or equivalent in Android Studio 3.2 to Enable ADB Integration

Tags: android-studio, adb

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 and need to Enable ADB Integration. In Android Studio <3.2 this was possible using `Find Action` or from Tools->Android as shown below:

[image: Android Studio <3.2 Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration]

On Android Studio 3.2.1 there is no Tools->Android visible and `Find Action` yields no suitable results for "ADB Integration"

[image: Android Studio 3.2.1 Tools menu bar contents]

There is a [post for a situation in 3.1 where the Android option does not appear](http://Android%20Studio%203.1%20does%20not%20showing%20'android'%20option%20under%20Tools%20menu) but the solutions provided in the answers do not work for 3.2

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49625983/7015599) the Android option has been removed from releases 3.1 onward.

How can I access the Tools->Android option or it's equivalent in Android Studio 3.2 in order to Enable ADB Integration?

Answer (score 1):

This is automatically available now at the app

[image]

And once click it will appear in the app profiler

[image]